# Python if a > b: b, a = a, b meaning

Tags: python

I just started self-learning Python and I stumble a sorting activity base on user input.

This is the code:

```
a = int(input("Enter Num1:"))
b = int(input("Enter Num2:"))
c = int(input("Enter Num3:"))
d = int(input("Enter Num4:"))

if a > b: b, a = a, b
if b > c: c, b = b, c
if c > d: d, c = c, d
if a > b: b, a = a, b
if b > c: c, b = b, c
if a > b: b, a = a, b

print(d, c, b, a)
```

I have a basic knowledge in `if-else statement` but I'm lost on what happened in this line `if a > b: b, a = a, b`. Please explain it to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a swap operation assigns value of a to b and vice versa.

```
a, b = 3, 4 # assign 3 to a, 4 to b
a, b = b, a
print(a, b) # prints "4 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

`x, y` is decomposed tuple, where `x` is first element of ordered pair and `y` is second. `=` is assignment operator. So basically `b, a = a, b` swaps values: `b` becomes `a` and `a` becomes `b`.

```
pair = (1, 2)
(x, y) = pair
x, y = pair  # you can omit parenthesis
x, y = y, x  # assign new values
```